# Spring Integration graph of Spring Tool Suite not showing “int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter” graphic

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-integration, spring-tool-suite

I'm currently using Spring Tool Suite (STS) (Version: 3.7.2.RELEASE, Build Id: 201511261048,Platform: Eclipse Mars.1 (4.5.1)) with Spring Integration 4.2.0.RELEASE and spring-integration-kafka version 1.3.0.RELEASE.

I have a Spring configuration XML file that includes the "integration" and "integration/kafka" namespaces. I've added a "int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter" to the config file. When I go into the integration-graph tab however I'm not seeing the icon/graphic for that component.

Sample config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" 
xmlns:int-kafka="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka" 
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/kafka/spring-integration-kafka.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <int-kafka:message-driven-channel-adapter
            id="kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter"
            channel="kafkaSubSpringExecutorChannel"
            connection-factory="kafkaConnectionFactory"
            offset-manager="kafkaTopicOffsetManager"
            max-fetch="100"
            topics="${kafka.test.topic}"/>
    <int:channel id="kafkaSubSpringExecutorChannel" />
</beans>
```

I believe this is a relatively new component.  Can it be added to the graphical editor?

Comment: Yes, support for this elements is missing... will add it for 3.7.3 release. Please open an issue as Gary suggests in his answer.

Comment: @Gary-Russell Created JIRA [STS-4295](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4295)

Answer (score 0):

The spring-integration-kafka project is still considered an extension to main Spring Integration project. We typically don't have support in STS for the extensions.

However, we are planning on bringing it into the core project some time next year.

In the meantime, try opening an 'improvement' [JIRA Issue in the STS Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS) to ask the STS team to consider adding it sooner.

If you open a ticket, please be sure to include a reference to this question/answer.